# Are your Uplay Unlocks shared between platforms?

Tags: ubisoft-connect

A few years ago, I ended up unlocking all of the Uplay Rewards for Far Cry 4 on the PlayStation 3. This was done directly from the game.

If I buy a Uplay game on PC that I have completed on another platform:

- Do I keep the rewards from the PS3 or they are treated as another game?
- Does this apply to all of the games or just specific ones?

Comment: Can't say for Far Cry 4, but in the case of Assassin's Creed 4: Black Flag, rewards were not shared between PS3, PS4, and Xbox One. Challenges were not shared either, so I got another shot at earning them for unlocking even more rewards.